# Jquery Filter showing erratic results

Tags: javascript, filter

I'm trying to set up a filter using jQuery. I'll have a certain amount of divs, each with a numeric value (let's say price).

The code below works fine, until you enter a value less than 10. Then you get results that shouldnt be there. (enter 4 for example)

Any help on fixing this would be great! thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/SUWxn/

```
<script>
function sortmebaby()
{
    var divList = $('#containerMonkey div[id^="monkey_"]');  

$.each(divList, function(index, value)
{
    console.log($(value).attr('xprice'));
    if ( $(value).attr('xprice') > $('#mankipower').val())
        $(value).hide();
    else
        $(value).show();
    //alert(index + ': ' + value);
});

}
</script>

<div id="containerMonkey">
    <div id="monkey_1" xprice="10">10</div>
    <div id="monkey_2" xprice="20">20</div>
    <div id="monkey_3" xprice="30">30</div>
    <div id="monkey_4" xprice="40">40</div>
    <div id="monkey_5" xprice="50">50</div>
</div>
<input type="text" name="mankipower" id="mankipower">
<input type="button" value="PUSH" onclick="sortmebaby()">
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition in your `if` statement is comparing strings, not integers as you're expecting. You can use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert the strings to numbers:

```
var val1 = parseInt($(value).attr('xprice'), 10),
    val2 = parseInt($('#mankipower').val(), 10);
if(val1 > val2)
    $(value).hide();
else
    $(value).show();
```

Here's an [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/SUWxn/2/).

Comment: Also, I would cache $(value) instead of reselecting it over and over.  And when you "hide" the element, its still in the DOM.  Use .remove() to literally remove it.

Comment: Agreed, caching `value` would be a good idea. As for your other suggestion, the elements can be hidden and shown again, so `hide` is much better in this case unless you want to recreate the elements every time and add them back into the DOM.